# MS-SQL Server Implicit_transaction on table

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I'm trying to experiment with implicit_transaction on sql server.
However, after executing:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;

INSERT INTO [Interface].[dbo].[Log] ([String], [Time], [theUser]) VALUES ((SELECT [String] FROM [Interface].[dbo].[Log] WHERE [ID] = '128'), null, 'ROW3');

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
```

However When I go to do a SELECT, the query hangs.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Transactions that are automatically opened as the result of this
>   setting being ON must be explicitly committed or rolled back by the
>   user at the end of the transaction. Otherwise, the transaction and all
>   of the data changes it contains are rolled back when the user
>   disconnects. After a transaction is committed, executing one of the
>   statements above starts a new transaction.

So, in effect, you did this:

```
begin transaction;
INSERT INTO [Interface].[dbo].[Log] ([String], [Time], [theUser]) 
VALUES ((SELECT [String] FROM [Interface].[dbo].[Log] WHERE [ID] = '128'), null, 'ROW3');
--no commit or rollback, so transaction is still open
```

In short, you have an open transaction that you need to do something with.